# MongoDB PHP define database connection

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using this approach to connect to remote database:
(SSH tunnel is running in background)

```
$mongo = new Mongo('mongodb://[root:password]@localhost:27018');
```

However I get error like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with
>   message 'Failed to connect to: localhost:27018: SASL Authentication
>   failed on database 'admin': Authentication failed.' in
>   /var/www/html/mongo_seed/index.php:22 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/mongo_seed/index.php(22):
>   Mongo->__construct('mongodb://[root...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/mongo_seed/index.php on line 22

How do I define which database I want to connect to inside parameter string? Or else how do I do the whole thing method by method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB spec says this:

> mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

I think you just have to add 
`/databasename` at the end?

Comment: Can you provide link for quoted text?

Answer (score 0):

`$connection = new MongoClient( "mongodb://[root:password]@localhost:27018" );`

Use this.